# How to mount "/" in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Saving Data in kubernetes is not persistant. so we should use volume.
Forexample we can mount "/apt" to save data in "apt".
Now I want to mount "/" but I get this error.

> Error: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
>   '/var/lib/kubelet/pods/26c39eeb-85d7-11e9-933c-7c8bca006fec/volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/pvc-d66d9039-853d-11e9-8aa3-7c8bca006fec:/':
>   invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid specification:
>   destination can't be '/'

The question is How can I mount "/" in kubernetes?

Comment: destination can't be '/'

Comment: How can i save any changes to my container?!

Comment: You want your entire container filesystem to be synced to the host somehow?  What's your use case?

Comment: yes . somehow
I have someuser . I want to save their entire changes

Comment: That's strange why would your user be updated when your application is used?

Comment: Your source might be root but destination should be some of other path, that is not used by your container (rootfs '/')

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure about your environment, but I ran into this issue today because I wanted to be able to browse the entire root filesystem of a container via SSH (WinSCP) to the host. I am using Docker in a Photon OS VM environment. The answer I've come to is: you can't do what you're trying to do, but you may be able to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish. Let's say I created a volume called mysql and I create a new (oversimplified) mysql container using that volume as root:

```
docker volume create --name mysql
docker run -d --name=mysqldb -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql:/ mysql:5.7
```

Docker will cry and say I can't mount to root (destination can't be '/'). However, since I know the location where our volumes live (/var/lib/docker/volumes/) then we can simply create our container as normal and an arbitrarily-named volume will be placed in that folder. So if your goal is (as mine was) to be able to ssh to the host and browse the files in the root of your container, you CAN do that, you just need to go to the correct arbitrarily-named volume. In my case it is "/var/lib/docker/volumes/12dccb66f2eeaeefe8e1feabb86f3c6def87b091dabeccad2902851caa97f04c/_data", which isn't as pretty as "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql", but it gets the job done.

Hope that helps someone.